# How many IKafkaProducer should I create in .net6 aspnet core for transactional use?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

I've created an aspnet .net6 core microservice which needs to produce messages to kafka topics. Often more than one, so I need for the producer to be transactional.

The problem is that for it to work I have to create a lock so when requests arrive, and Store method is called from many different threads, the BeginTransaction won't get called second time without the CommitTransaction or AbortTransaction being called.

```
public void Store(IMessageContext mc, StoreDelegate storeMessageDelegate) {
        lock(transactionLock) {
            this.kafkaProducer.BeginTransaction();
            try {
                storeMessageDelegate.Invoke(new StoreProducer(mc, this.kafkaProducer));
                this.kafkaProducer.CommitTransaction();
            }
            catch(Exception) {
                this.kafkaProducer.AbortTransaction(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

So, the question is... Should I create many identical Producers and use SemaphoreSlim for example to control them? Or maybe there is some other method?

The lock used in above code slows down request a lot when there is a lot of threads at once.

Comment: You only need one producer client for multiple topics, assuming your producer config can be the same for all those topics

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question is how to produce messages (in transaction) from aspnet application without the lock command as it's slowing everything down a lot.

Comment: According to the title of the post, you're asking how many IKafkaProducer you should create. And I'm saying you only need one. Locks slow things down, sure, that's the point. Doesn't change the fact that you are only locking one producer instance, though. If you want a looser producer to use without transactions and apply different configurations, then create another. They shouldn't share any memory space

Comment: What is the point of the post content if people only answer the title? As i found out, spring for example in certain configuration creates many identical producers so producing messages is faster.

Comment: I didn't answer;. it's just a comment, but Spring will use multiple concurrent threads with Kafka **Streams** API. I don't think it does that with a producer. Definitely not a transactional one